# Guaranteed Delivery of messages using Redis

Tags: spring, redis, spring-integration

I'm trying to make the messages of a QueueChannel persistent, even if the application is killed, I need the messages to carry on being processed after the application starts again.
I'm aware that it's easy to get done with QueueChannel backed by a JdbcChannelMessageStore processed by a ServiceActivator with a transactional poller, but **I must use Redis for this task**.

Given this, I have tried QueueChannel backed by a RedisChannelMessageStore processed by a ServiceActivator with a transactional poller. It works well for messages that are in the queue to be processed, but the messages that are being processed at the moment of the kill are lost.

I would like to know if there is any spring-integration component or pattern that could be used in this case.

I'm considering the possibility of doing it by hand. When the message comes in, I put into the Redis, when it finishes processing I remove it, and at the application's startup  I read the messages from Redis (if there is any) to the channel. But I'm not comfortable with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The `Poller` of the endpoint for that `QueueChannel` can be configured with the `TransactionSynchronizationFactory`, where a `DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory` implementation can be configured to resend a message back to the queue via `ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.3.RELEASE/reference/html/transactions.html#transaction-synchronization

Comment: I've seen that, but I do not even test it as it does not seem to work for my case.
When the message is delivered to the ServiceActivator it is not on the RedisChannelMessageStore anymore. Then, if the application gets killed while processing a message, I do not even have the oportunity to put it on the MessageStore again (considering that I would write some code on "processAfterRollback" to put the message on MessageStore again in case of rollback).
Please, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yeah... I agree with you. Need to think more. Although so far your idea about custom solution makes sense

Comment: I tried with `enableTransactionSupport` for the `RedisTemplate`,  but looks like any read operations can't be used within transactions. Even if Redis list size > 0, the `BRPOP` in the separate TX still returns for me `null`... So, your won solution sounds good.